# BIGQUERY equivalents of sign(bitand...) function

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to decode one column on Big Query. In Oracle SQL Developer I used

```
sign(bitand(column, power(2,18)))
```

Can I use its equivalent on Big Query?

Comment: What function are you actually performing here, are you looking to see if the numbers are equal?

Comment: In Oracle this function decodes certain feature of column "column" (inside are big numbers). Number 18 defines certain feature. As a result "sign(bitand(column, power(2,18)))" returns 1 (if a feature is fullfilled) and 0 if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You can use

```
SIGN(column & CAST(POWER(2,18) AS INT64))
```